# Click on <tr> element with trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

I've small problem with trigger (jQuery). In my `<table>`, i would like if I click on my `<tr>` it ove my href.

See my code/test at http://jsfiddle.net/vPEAn/

```
$('tr').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.link').trigger('click');  
});
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: You could still trigger the native click event: `$(this).find('.link')[0].click();` http://jsfiddle.net/vPEAn/2/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is manually triggering a (jquery)click event on an anchor tag doesn't perform the default action. Instead, just do a normal javascript redirect.

```
$('tr').click(function(){
    window.location.href = $(this).find('.link').attr("href");  
});
```

Comment: Hi :) Thak you for your post, but if i add other link, it's don't work :(

Comment: Well of course it doesn't. how do you know which link to target if there are two?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the url to a variable:

```
$('tr').click(function(){
    var url = $(this).find('.link').attr('href');
    window.location = url;
});
```

Comment: You could, but you might want to store the href value of the anchor tag rather than a jQuery object.